# Autocompiling Sass\Scss using vimscript (vimrc)

Tags: regex, vim, sass, neovim

I want: autocompile sass/scss files to .css automatically on save.

What I've done:

init.vim (vimrc):

```
autocmd bufwritepost *.sass,*.scss  silent exec "!sass %:p %:r.css"
```

It works fine, but when I want to change some module like: **_module.sass**, obviously, the command executes and I have unnecessary compiled **_module.css** in my project folder (unnecessary because I already include it to **main.sass** and I don't need it to compile separately).

May be solution is to add some **if** statement that will be using regex to check if a file's name starts with "_" symbol, but I don't know how to implement this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the `autocmd` to trigger if the filename doesn't start with an underscore, you can use

```
autocmd bufwritepost [^_]*.sass,[^_]*.scss  silent exec "!sass %:p %:r.css"
```

You can read about all of the rules for `autocmd` patterns using vim's built in help:

```
:h autocmd-pattern
```